# Symfony3 | добавить/записать в форму значение по умолчанию

Tags: form, symfony2, symfony, symfony3

Добрый день.
Я хотел бы добавить в форму по умолчанию выбранного автора в поле hidden. Добавление происходит как положено, но во время записи получаю:

```
Could not determine access type for property "id".
```

Теперь по порядку:

Controller. *Здесь я задаю значение mentor по умолчанию. И в форме все как положено показывается.*

```
public function newAction(Request $request)
{
    $meeting = new Meeting();

    $meeting->setMentor($this->getUser());

    $form = $this->createForm('App\AdminBundle\Form\MeetingType', $meeting);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($meeting);
        $em->flush($meeting);

        return $this->redirectToRoute('meeting_show', array('id' => $meeting->getId()));
    }

    return $this->render('meeting/new.html.twig', array(
        'meeting' => $meeting,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

Форма.

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{   
    $builder
        ...
        ->add('mentor', HiddenType::class,[
            'property_path' => 'mentor.id'
        ])
        ...
}
```

И, собственно, поле данной формы в html. Тут все отлично.

```
<input type="hidden" id="app_adminbundle_meeting_mentor" name="app_adminbundle_meeting[mentor]" value="1">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В классе вашего пользователя (ментора) нет стандартного способа задать ID.
При записи symfony пытается записать туда значение (id), но не может этого сделать т.к. нет сеттера (`setId($id)`), а само свойство не публичное.

Варианты:

1. Вам действительно нужно это поле в форме? Возможно имеет смысл вызывать `$meeting->setMentor($this->getUser());` только перед записью в БД.
2. Чтобы форма не пыталась записать значение в объект можно задать полю опцию `mapped => false`, но тогда придётся вручную задать значение для поля: `data => $id`, в целом это будет выглядеть так:

`->add('mentor', HiddenType::class,[
    'mapped' => false,
    'data' => $id,
])`

3. Использовать [DataMapper](https://webmozart.io/blog/2015/09/09/value-objects-in-symfony-forms/#data-mappers). Кстати, о них знают не многие т.к. в документации они почему-то пропущены, а штука очень мощная.
4. Добавить метод setId($id) в класс пользователя, можно просто функцию без тела. Этот метод решения весьма сомнительный, хотя будет работать. Но, ещё раз, хотя бы по эстетическим причинам не стоит этого делать.

Comment: мда, что-то я себя идиотом почувствовал. Первый вариант по сути и был единственно верным, на самом деле. Не могу понять, зачем я вообще перед сабмитом пихал участника. Усложнил задачу только. Спасибо за помощь. А за **DateMapper** отдельное спасибо, сейчас получше ознакомлюсь :)